# Android: Populate ListView in a fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, fragment

I have a activity that fills a ListView, and it is working. Because I use a tabs ViewPager, I have to use fragments instead of activities. So can somebody tell me what I need to change to make a fragment from my activity (FragmentActivity cannot be used in tabs).

```
package com.basnijkamp.safanagendatest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ListSample extends Activity {  

    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";  
    public final static String ITEM_CAPTION = "caption";  

    public Map<String,?> createItem(String title, String caption) {  
        Map<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();  
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);  
        item.put(ITEM_CAPTION, caption);  
        return item;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
        super.onCreate(icicle);  

        List<Map<String,?>> september2012 = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
        september2012.add(createItem("Electra Mining Africa 2012", "Johannesberg South Africa"));  
        september2012.add(createItem("MSV", "Brno Czech Republic"));  
        september2012.add(createItem("IMTS", "Chicago USA"));
        september2012.add(createItem("AMB", "Stuttgart Germany"));  
        september2012.add(createItem("Den Teknise Messe", "Lillestrom Norway"));  
        september2012.add(createItem("ITM", "Plovdiv Bulgaria"));  

        List<Map<String,?>> oktober2012 = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
        oktober2012.add(createItem("BIMU", "Milan Italy"));  
        oktober2012.add(createItem("Matek", "Istanbul"));
        oktober2012.add(createItem("TIB", "Bucharest Romania"));
        oktober2012.add(createItem("Vienna Tec", "Vienna Austria"));
        oktober2012.add(createItem("Euro Blech 2012", "Hanover Germany"));
        oktober2012.add(createItem("Technica Massan", "Stockholm Sweden"));

        List<Map<String,?>> november2012 = new LinkedList<Map<String,?>>();  
        november2012.add(createItem("JIMTOF", "Tokyo Japan"));
        november2012.add(createItem("Metavak", "Gorinchem Netherlands"));
        november2012.add(createItem("FABTECH", "Las Vegas USA"));
        november2012.add(createItem("Prodex", "Basel Switzerland"));
        november2012.add(createItem("EMAF 2012", "Porto Portugal"));
        november2012.add(createItem("Manufact Indonesia", "Jakarta Indonesia"));

        // create our list and custom adapter  
        SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);  
        adapter.addSection("September 2012", new SimpleAdapter(this, september2012, R.layout.list_complex,   
            new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));
        adapter.addSection("Oktober 2012", new SimpleAdapter(this, oktober2012, R.layout.list_complex,   
            new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));
        adapter.addSection("November 2012", new SimpleAdapter(this, november2012, R.layout.list_complex,   
                new String[] { ITEM_TITLE, ITEM_CAPTION }, new int[] { R.id.list_complex_title, R.id.list_complex_caption }));

        ListView list = new ListView(this);  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);  
        this.setContentView(list);  

    }  

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to extends ListFragment - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html .

So from this:

```
        ListView list = new ListView(this); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter); 
        this.setContentView(list);
```

you should do this:

```
        setListAdapter (adapter);
```

from

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle);
```

->

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
```

and from `ListSample extends Activity` -> `ListSample extends ListFragment`

Let me know if more details needed, good luck

Comment: on "public void onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)" do i need to remove the override? and "savedInstanceState" cannot be resolved as a type

Comment: Now the SeparatedListAdapter causes problems "The constructor SeparatedListAdapter(AgendaTab) is undefined
" Here is the code for the separatelistadapter(password:android) http://plaatscode.be/141890/ i think i am almost at the solution

Comment: That is easy - the adapter requires the context in the constructor. Activity extended Context, but Fragment not, so you must make new SeparatedListAdapter(getActivity()) instead of new SeparatedListAdapter(this)

Comment: yeah! and the last thing "The constructor SimpleAdapter(AgendaTab, List<Map<String,?>>, int, String[], int[]) is undefined" can you please help me with this last thing :)

Comment: Isn't it the same case? Just replace first 'this' to getActivity()

Comment: Are you a superhero? I think you are you just saved my day!